# Why do the icon and text come in same line?

Tags: html, css, google-material-icons

When I display an icon and some text along with it, I want them to come in the same line. I can achieve this when I use the `<div>` tag. However, it isn't achieved when I use the `<p>` tag. Why so?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
i {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <i class="material-icons">call</i>
  <!-- <div>9988998899</div> -->
  <p>9988998899</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `p` tag by default has a `margin` value which you need to reset, or set the `align-items` property. With `div` tags also, you will notice that the elements are aligned according to their top borders (not in line), which you can achieve with `align-items`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}

.c1 p {
  margin: 0;
}

.c2, .c4 {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<pre>// p with margin: 0</pre>
<div class="container c1">
  <i class="material-icons">call</i>
  <p>9988998899</p>
</div>

<pre>// p without margin: 0, but align-items:center</pre>
<div class="container c2">
  <i class="material-icons">call</i>
  <p>9988998899</p>
</div>

<pre>// div without align-items:center</pre>
<div class="container c3">
  <i class="material-icons">call</i>
  <div>9988998899</div>
</div>

<pre>// div with align-items:center</pre>
<div class="container c4">
  <i class="material-icons">call</i>
  <div>9988998899</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but why didn't we need to do this when we used `<div>` tag?

Comment: Edited my answer, have a look